# How to save UITextField Text to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my main view controller, I have a UITextField, and I am trying to save the text input into  it to a NSString in my Homework model(class).

Homework.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Homework : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentTitle;


@end
```

Homework.m

```
#import "Homework.h"

@implementation Homework

@synthesize className = _className;
@synthesize assignmentTitle = _assignmentTitle;

@end
```

In my assignmentViewController, I create an object of type Homework and try to set it equal to whatever is entered into the the UITextField when the Save Button is pressed.

Assignment View Controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Homework.h"

@interface Assignment : UIViewController {


}

@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ClassNameField;
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ClassNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *SaveButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Homework *homeworkAssignment;


- (IBAction)Save:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

AssignmentViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)Save:(UIButton *)sender {

self.homeworkAssignment.className = self.ClassNameField.text;
NSLog(@"SaveButtonPressed %@", self.homeworkAssignment.className);

}
```

The NSLog prints out that className is (null).  Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? This is my first ever  iOS app (besides Hello World).

Edit: This is using ARC

Edit: I tried changing
    self.homeworkAssignment.className = self.ClassNameField.text; to
    self.homeworkAssignment.className = @"TEST"; 
and the log still shows (Null).

Comment: Check the property definition for ClassNameField.  There should be a little circle in the left margin on the editor.  There will be a dot in the center of the circle if the field is properly linked.  If the dot is not there then ClassNameField will be nil.

Comment: @HotLicks - ClassNameField is linked properly

Comment: If self.homeworkAssignment.className = @"TEST" prints null, `homeworkAssignment` is definitely `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check you properly linked `ClassNameField` *outlet* and that you're initializing `homeworkAssignment`. Something like.-

```
self.homeworkAssignment = [[Homework alloc] init];
```

---

By the way, you should consider using *camelCase* notation for your variable names :)

Comment: ClassNameField is linked properly, also this is using ARC, so I just did @synthesize homeworkAssignment = _homeworkAssignment;

Comment: Well, ARC will `release` objects for you, but doesn't mean you don't have to `alloc` them. My bet is that `homeworkAssignment` is `nil` due to the missing `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest the first steps are always hard but you should learn it the right way, héhé

**First of all synthesize this way:**

```
@synthesize labelAssignmentTitle,labelClassName;
```

or

```
@synthesize labelAssignmentTitle;
@synthesize labelClassName;
```

there is **no** need to do the following:

```
@synthesize className = _className;
@synthesize assignmentTitle = _assignmentTitle;
```

**Now if you initialize the right way from the the start you'll find it a lot easier later!**

**HomeWork.h**

```
@interface HomeWork : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentTitle;

-(id)initWithClassName:(NSString *)newClassName andAssignmentTitle:(NSString*)newAssigmentTitle;
```

**HomeWork.m**

```
@implementation HomeWork
@synthesize assignmentTitle,className;

-(id)initWithClassName:(NSString *)newClassName andAssignmentTitle:(NSString*)newAssigmentTitle {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        assignmentTitle = newAssigmentTitle;
        className = newClass;

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)saveIt:(id)sender {
    HomeWork *newHomeWork = [[HomeWork alloc]initWithClassName:[labelClassName text]andAssignmentTitle:[labelAssignmentTitle text]];
}
```

Because of this, you directly make a newHomeWork object with the parameters given by your two UITextFields.

Now print it out in your logmessage and see what happends ;)

Comment: No problem, try to figure out the initWith... methods they'll help you in the future!
BTW what the 'self = [super init]' is etc, will come later! 
A good book on the matter is : Objective-C For Absolute Beginners